# How to format a dateline using php?

Tags: php, date

I'm wondering how to make the datelines looks like the same.

e.g

2007-7, 200707 => 2007-07

Thanks!

Comment: from where these values (2007-7, 200707) did come?

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date):

```
 echo date('Y-m', strtotime($your_dateline));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date('Y-m', time());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below script...

```
echo date('Y-m', date());

           or 

echo date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2007));
```